# c++ When does terminating program's memory leak matter?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

I read [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) article saying

> Memory leaks may not be serious or even detectable by normal means. In
>   modern operating systems, normal memory used by an application is
>   released when the application terminates. This means that a memory
>   leak in a program that only runs for a short time may not be noticed
>   and is rarely serious.

OS automatically release normal memory when terminating. Therefore, if memory leak was not serious by all means, leaked memory by program may not be matter after termination.

But it mentions only in case of "normal memory" and I got worried.
Could anyone explain what non-normal memory means?

Comment: In the 3rd bullet point right after the part you refer to, it mentions shared memory, which would not get automatically released at termination.

Comment: @Dan Mašek What is shared memory? Does it mean memory shared through processes?

Comment: Yes, used as an IPC mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

How about few philosophical reasons? 
For starters, if you ever need to redesign concept of lifetime in your program later, such as switch to  a service, dll, multidoc support, or something like that, addressing this will become a must and an extra cost. Secondly, if the program does not free memory, chances are it does not release other critical resources, file locks on servers, for example (pure speculation, of course, I do not know what your program does).

But memory release on process termination will be guaranteed, outside of real-time systems on specialized  hardware. Those can behave very differently.

Answer (score 0):

In general; A program that leaks memory is only a problem while that program is running. It will take up more memory than it needs and may even run out. But, as soon as the program terminates, the OS kernel reclaims all memory that the program ever allocated, so it will all be free again and available for other uses.

It's actually a fairly common trick to intentionally leak memory on shutdown in some cases. If you *know* that your objects destructors don't do any work that is of any consequence if the program is shutting down anyway, then it can be faster to just leak the objects and let the OS clean up when you are terminating, rather than running all the destructors. However; only do that if you have a good reason to and *really* know what you are doing and why you are doing it.

Comment: Yes, the speed was one of my concern from the beginning. The other was about a detached thread. I had several occasions I had to detach my thread. I was little worried about the resources in detached thread after termination. It's great comfort to hear it's common trick.